# Pulling multiple values from JSON response using 'Json Path Extractor ' in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

```
{
    "response_time": 0.014376163482666016,
    "applications": [
        {
            "api_key": "blted0e7982e1cf62a8",
            "name": "gta",
            "uid": "gta",
            "account_name": "jack"
        },
        {
            "api_key": "blt1423c40d23e4a423",
            "name": "cellapp",
            "uid": "cellapp",
            "account_name": "max"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me to extract the `account_name = max` using Jmeter `Json Path Extractor`.

Comment: in above example i want to extract "account_name": "max" using Json path extractor i m using $.applications.account_name but it gives me account_name = jack

Comment: you have to loop through your result.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor
if my response contains multiple account's what should i use for extraction in such case

Comment: @Shivan Raptor
how we can do it, in a Jmeter for REST Api calls testing

Answer (score 5):

`$.applications.name[2]` must return exactly the second name element.

If you use `JSONPath` like `$..name` this will look for all elements named `name` and the plugin will return a single string value which will look like `["gta","cellapp"]`. You can parse this string if necessary.

Check the this site on how to build JSONPath expressions:
http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2.

Comment: Correct expression will look like `$.applications[1].account_name`: 1. question was about "account_name", not "name" field; 2. indexes start from 0, not from 1; so the 2nd element will be [1]; 3. as well you have to refer to point index for "applications" item, not for name.

Answer (score 3):

With the expresion ->

```
$.[?(@.account_name=='max')].account_name
```

You will get

```
[
  "max"
]
```

With the expresion ->

```
$.[?(@.account_name=='max')]
```

You will get

```
[
    {
        "api_key": "blt1423c40d23e4a423",
        "name": "cellapp",
        "uid": "cellapp",
        "account_name": "max"
    }
]
```

With the expresion ->

```
$.[?(/max/.test(@.account_name))]
```

You will get a "like" condition

```
[
    {
        "api_key": "blt1423c40d23e4a423",
        "name": "cellapp",
        "uid": "cellapp",
        "account_name": "max"
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$..[?(@.account_name =='max')].account_name
```